# Event Emitter Library with priority levels?

Tags: javascript, events, eventemitter

Can someone recommend a small event library (ES5) that lets you set a priority level when binding to the event? It can be jquery-based or vanilla javascript.
I've only seen one so far, called Signal Emitter: (http://blog.millermedeiros.com/signal-emitter/)  But I figure there's gotta be more out there.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go for the out of box order that can be set by using `prependListener` have a look at this example:

```
const myEE = new EventEmitter();
myEE.on('foo', () => console.log('a'));
myEE.prependListener('foo', () => console.log('b'));
myEE.emit('foo');
// Prints:
//   b
//   a
```

> By default, event listeners are invoked in the order they are added. The emitter.prependListener() method can be used as an alternative to add the event listener to the beginning of the listeners array.